# iOS: How to hide a UITextField on settings change?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a settings screen in which I set the units for the app. The user can go from the main screen to the settings screen and after selecting the desired unit, the settings screen is dismissed.

When the user returns to the main screen, I want to hide and show two UITextField.

I tried the following code in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` but doesn't work:

```
textBox1.hidden = YES;
textBox2.hidden = NO;
```

This may be trivial but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I have connected the 'Settings' screen with `Sugue` using `push` and dismiss the settings screen using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` which leads the user back to main screen. Now, I need to refresh the screen controls based on the settings and it's not working

Comment: Did you create them in code or in a XIB or Storyboard? If created in a xib or Storyboard make sure the outlets are set correctly.. Also just try `[textBox1 setHidden:YES];`

Comment: I created the UI in storyboard and have ensured that the outlets are connected..

Comment: I tried `viewWillAppear` as well :)

Comment: Instead of hiding try to put some text in to insure its all connected correctly: `[textBox1 setText:@"test"];`

Comment: @RyanG: Hey, you are right - the text is not getting set.. weird..But when I close the app and again open it, it show the desired result for the first time only... Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe remove the IBOutlets and re-create them? It doesn't take much for them to get screwed up

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but can you post it as an answer with suggestion as to how to remove and re-create the IBOutlets?

Comment: Not a dumb question-- I will have it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for taking time.. I just realized the my code for reading the value for the boolean key from `NSUserDefaults` was in `viewDidLoad` which only gets called once :)

I moved that line of code to `viewWillAppear` and everything works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

first:
shouldn't it be

```
self.textBox1 = YES; // or [self.textBox1 setHidden:YES];
self.textBox2 = NO; // or [self.textBox2 setHidden:NO];
```

Second:
make sure that outlets are not null

```
NSLog("textBox1 = %@" , self.textBox1);
```

Third:
Try some code like this

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 15.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  self.textBox1.hidden = YES;
  self.textBox2.hidden = NO ;
});
```

Do this in your viewWillAppear or DidAppear.  Then in 15 seconds you will see the changes if everything is wired correctly.

Comment: Hey, that works! Thanks. But I honestly don't want a delay! Is there something that can be done to avoid delay?

Comment: That's assuming he's going back to the previous view within trhe 15 sec right? Else it would even crash if I'm seeing it right?

Comment: for what you are trying to do, the delay was there just so that you can see the view.  I would wonder why a delay is needed.  It should been needed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following bools to yes or no (in the settings screen).

```
BOOL hideTextBox1;
BOOL hideTextBox2;
```

Save the variable (in the settings screen):

```
NSString *hideTextBox1String;
NSString *hideTextBox2String;

if(hideTextBox1 == YES){
    hideTextBox1String = @"YES"
}else{
    hideTextBox1String = nil
}

if(hideTextBox2 == YES){
    hideTextBox2String = @"YES"
}else{
    hideTextBox2String = nil
}

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:hideTextBox2String  forKey:@"hideTextBox2"];
[defaults setObject:hideTextBox1String  forKey:@"hideTextBox1"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Retrieve it in the first viewcontroller:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *hideBox1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"hideTextBox1"];
NSString *hideBox2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"hideTextBox2"];

if(hideBox1 != nil){
    textBox1.hidden = YES;
}else{
    textBox1.hidden = NO;
}

if(hideBox2 != nil){
    textBox2.hidden = YES;
}else{
    textBox2.hidden = NO;
}
```

This will make the change permanent untill you change back. Guess that's what youre looking for.

Comment: With the first part I mean that you should give them a value yourself, whether you want them to be YES or NO.

Comment: I'm doing similar thing: I'm setting a boolean value in my settings, reading that value when the main screen again appears, but after setting the boolean in `NSUserDefaults` when I read and execute the code (written in my question), the textboxes don't hide... any idea what could be wrong or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since setting the text does not work either I am guessing your IBOutlets may be messed up. To re-do them do the following:

1. First go into your Storyboard & zoom into the view controller that your working on
2. Control + Click your UITextView or UITextField, you will see a similar menu:
   [image]

You can see that I have an IBOutlet set named txtCaseID

3. If you see an outlet set like I do, go ahead and click the X to remove it
4. To re-add this outlet, open up the Assistance Editor to view the Storyboard & your .h
5. Control + Click & Drag from your textBox in your Storyboard to the IBOutlet you made previously in your .h like so:

[image]

Make sure to do this for both textBoxes. 
Let me know if you need any other help--